# Reference request for statement concerning free subgroups of $ \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}). $

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry

I am interested in finding a reference for the following claim:

There exists a free subgroup $F_2$ of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ on two generators that does not contain any nontrivial unipotent elements.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: one can show that the commutator subgroup of the congruence subgroup $\Gamma (2)$ of level 2 in $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$ does not contain unipotent elements, but is free on infinitely many generators. You can then take any two elements in the generating set.

Comment: Much more is true: Every Zariski dense subgroup of $SL(n,R)$ contains a free subgroup without nontrivial unipotents. This is due to J.Tits

Comment: It seems to be the easiest instance of the ping-pong lemma, which implies that every Zariski-dense subgroup of $\mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbf{R})$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $F_2$ and QI-embedded in $\mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbf{R})$. That it is QI-embedded prevents the existence of unipotents.

Comment: It’s a fine question, but not appropriate for mathoverflow which is aimed at research-level questions.

Comment: @IanAgol - I agree that the math question is not research level, but what about the reference request? I’ve had a few times when I’ve tried (and failed) to find a perfect reference for something a bit easy… which I still did not want to prove myself…

Answer (score 2):

Consider the hyperbolic matrices
$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\quad
\mbox{and}
\quad
b = 
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 \\
-1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Working in the upper half plane model of $\mathbb{H}^2$, we take $a$ to be the (oriented!) geodesic from $0$ to $-1$ and $a'$ to be the geodesic from $1$ to $\infty$.  Similarly, take $b$ to be the geodesic from $0$ to $1$ and $b'$ to be the geodesic from $-1$ to $\infty$.  (It helps to draw a figure at this point.) Then $A$ takes $a$ to $a'$ and $B$ takes $b$ to $b'$, all preserving orientations.  Also, the axis of $A$ is transverse to (but not perpendicular to) $a$ and $a'$; similarly the axis of $B$ is transverse to $b$ and $b'$.

We deduce that $A$ and $B$ generate a free rank two subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$.  However, their commutator $ABA^{-1}B^{-1}$ is parabolic.  So, to answer the original question, we instead consider the subgroup generated by $A^2$ and $B^2$.  A standard "ping-pong" argument shows that these generate a free group of rank two where all non-identity elements are hyperbolic.

---

I poked around in a few standard references, but did not find this exact statement. However it is "easily" deduced from material in various places.  For example, you may enjoy reading Chapter 3 of *Noneuclidean tesselations and their groups* by Wilhelm Magnus.  (Note the amazing collection of illustrations, mostly taken from the works of Fricke and Klein, starting on page 159.) In a somewhat different direction, you could use the "combination theorem" of Klein-Maskit.  See Section VIII.A.1 of *Kleinian groups* by Bernard Maskit.

Comment: Schottky might be among the references?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not read German even nearly well enough.  At a quick skim, Schottky's 1877 paper is mostly about uniformisation, and does not have many examples (and certainly no explicit two-by-two integer matrices...)